# How to safely use a USB bus powered device in a car

Tags: usb, voltage-regulator, audio, automotive, charger

I want to use a USB bus powered USB 2.0 audio interface in my car for DSP.
Specifically a MOTU Microbook II https://motu.com/products/motuaudio/microbook_old

My car doesn't have a USB port near the install location, but there is a cigarette lighter socket.

- 99,9% cig lighter USB converters seem to be designed for phone charging, but does it matter?

  - Nowadays there are three zillon phone charging standards. Is some of them same as USB 2.0 bus power, and is it standardly supported in all of them (low power device, high power device etc)? Do I need to shop for a specific kind of charger?
  - Do they have the necessary protection circuits that a non-phone USB device will not suffer from the car's unstable power supply?
- Do USB powered devices internally have the necessary protection circuits, or do they just assume that USB power is clean?
- Is there an industry standard way of handling cigarette lighter sockets in cars during starting? Disconnect power during cranking, or just always on?

  - No problem if the power is disconnected, I'm just worrying about damaging surges.
- Would I be better off using some other generic voltage converter/regulator with a DIY USB cable?

TLDR How to safely use a USB bus powered device in a car? Am I overthinking it?

Comment: Why don’t you measure what happens to the voltage at the cigar lighter during starting and running? Be better than typing guesses into the www…

Comment: I would say that most USB devices assume some sort of stability and they have limited, if any, protection, so the best thing for you is to assume they want no more than 5.5V. The typical 5% tolerance means the "5V" can be from 4.75V to 5.25V. I have seen chargers with 5.3V. Most 5V devices tolerate up to 5.5V in normal operation, some up to 6V, but it's best to set about 5.2V, that way it is a bit higher to allow for some voltage drop on the power line, but if it changes over time at least you have a bit of headroom to keep it from going too high.

Comment: There is no way all these questions about all these devices in general can be answered or the specific car and USB device you have. USB chargers may be ripply because they are intended mostly for phone charging. It may be too ripply for sensitive audio devices and it may make a ground loop which further makes situation worse. On the other hand, a sensitive audio device should be expected to at least filter the supply to allow for some ripple. The car USB chargers are just as likely to damage your phone than your audio interface. Use a powerbank to isolate from car, but they may be ripply too.